# Having open windows

Tags: c#, windows

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [C# - Get list of open tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310456/c-get-list-of-open-tasks)
>   [On Windows XP, how do I enumerate all the windows displayed by the system (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416600/on-windows-xp-how-do-i-enumerate-all-the-windows-displayed-by-the-system-c)

Hello,

I want to make a program in C#, to know how many windows are open operating system (in this case, the Windows operating system)

I guess I'll have to use the library user32.dll, right?

Can anyone tell me where I can see an example of code to manage windows?

Thanks for the help.
Greetings!

Comment: what do you mean by "to know how many windows are open operating system?"

Comment: Seems very similar to [C# - Get list of open tasks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310456/c-get-list-of-open-tasks) and [On Windows XP, how do I enumerate all the windows displayed by the system (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416600/on-windows-xp-how-do-i-enumerate-all-the-windows-displayed-by-the-system-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find something useful [here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.EnumDesktopWindows).