# How can I monitor the Task queues in the .NET TaskSchedulers (across AppDomain)

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, task, monitoring

As a developer, I would like to monitor the size (and progress) of work in the Task Queues in the TaskSchedulers so that I can evaluate whether an experienced slowdown under production load is due to the magnitude or perhaps stall of tasks scheduled.

Normally I would simply attach the debugger and inspect task sizes, but:

1. The application is running under mono and in production, so I cannot attach to it using visual studio
2. I would like to deliver output of analysis on this data as surveillance input for health-monitoring of the service

I have been through the docs and found

- [TaskScheduler.GetScheduledTasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.getscheduledtasks%28v=vs.100%29.aspX), which delivers this information to the debugger. It is protected (which I could circumvent), but also seem to require some guarantees about frozen threads which I cannot honor. However, I am willing to use inconsistent data.
- [how to get a list of running tasks in .net 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829793/how-to-get-a-list-of-running-tasks-in-net-4-0). Which focuses on the *running* Tasks, which are not that interesting to me. I am interested in the size of the backlog and whether work is progressing.

I am willing to:

1. Use code designed for other purposes (such as for the debugger)
2. Accept that i get inconsistent data (this is for statistics and analysis)

Things that I do *not* want to do are:

1. Add tracking to each task created.

   - Some of the code is 3rd party and cannot be refactored
   - There is *lots* of code, and injecting this into that is worse than not being able to tell how it is progressing.
2. Use a custom TaskScheduler

   - Some of the code is 3rd party and cannot be refactored
   - Some of the code use TaskSchedulers which sets thread-priority and max-concurrency. Factoring in the monitoring aspect would be awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the `TaskScheduler.GetScheduledTasks` is designed for debuggers only and there is no direct way to get scheduled tasks.

But MSDN says ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.getscheduledtasks(v=vs.100).aspx)):

> Developers who are implementing custom debuggers shouldn't call this method directly, but should use the internal wrapper method `GetScheduledTasksForDebugger` instead: `internal Task[] GetScheduledTasksForDebugger()`. This wrapper method returns an array of tasks instead of an enumerable. To retrieve a list of active schedulers, use the internal method `internal static TaskScheduler[] GetTaskSchedulersForDebugger()`. This static method returns an array of all active TaskScheduler instances. You can then use `GetScheduledTasksForDebugger` on each scheduler instance to retrieve its list of scheduled tasks.

So why not use reflection? This is a safe and easy way to achieve what you want because `GetScheduledTasksForDebugger` will exist in future and it's designed for debugging and probably for profiling.

Answer (score 3):

I am able to retrieve the information using reflection and the GetScheduledTasksForDebugger:

```
public static class ScheduledTaskAccess
{
    public static Task[] GetScheduledTasksForDebugger(this TaskScheduler ts)
    {
        var mi = ts.GetType().GetMethod("GetScheduledTasksForDebugger", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (mi == null)
            return null;
        return (Task[])mi.Invoke(ts, new object[0]);
    }
    public static TaskScheduler[] GetTaskSchedulersForDebugger()
    {
        var mi = typeof(TaskScheduler).GetMethod("GetTaskSchedulersForDebugger", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
        if (mi == null)
            return null;
        return (TaskScheduler[])mi.Invoke(null, new object[0]);
    }
}
```

using a custom IEqualityComparer I am able to maintain how long they have been queued. Very useful meta-information :)

Now I just wish there was some statistics on the the tasks that one could access, CPU-time spent, idle-time, task-switchcount, ...

Comment: After running the above code for some time in production, I now know that it sometimes crashes mono :(

Comment: Even if using "GetTaskSchedulersForDebugger()" is completely discouraged by Microsoft, well done ! I tested, it works ! I thought it was completely impossible.